# Bundled SSL Certificate Public Key does not match Private Key Public Key

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, traefik

I am trying to install a new SSL certificate into Traefik. My certificate is signed by a third party (Setigo), and was provided to me with the chain:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[[SNIP - Root CA]]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[[SNIP - Intermediate CA]]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[[SNIP - Intermediate CA]]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[[SNIP - MyServer Cert]]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The last certificate in the chain matches the individual certificate. When I pass that certificate and coresponding key to Traefik, I get the following error:

```
failed to load X509 key pair: tls: private key does not match public key
```

Researching online, I have found these commands to verify the public keys/modulus for the cert and private key

```
openssl rsa -modulus -noout -in myserver.key | openssl md5

openssl x509 -modulus -noout -in myserver.crt | openssl md5
```

When I run this against the chained cert the results do not match. When I run it against the individual cert it matches.

I can not use the individual cert, as it is not signed by a trusted root, so I get the following error when using OpenSSL s_client:

```
openssl s_client -connect myserver:443 -showcerts
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
```

I'm wracking my brain here, what am I missing???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your chain is wrong.  You need to reverse it and drop the root CA certificate.

The server is thinking the root CA is the main certificate and it's trying to load the private key against the root ca certificate which it why you are seeing the message.

Also there is no need for the root CA as this should always be in the clients CA list, so you are sending the CA certificate to the client and the client will just ignore it.

i.e.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[[SNIP - MyServer Cert]]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[[SNIP - Intermediate CA]]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[[SNIP - Intermediate CA]]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: This looks like it was exactly the issue. I don't know why our certificate manager generates the bundle backwards, but reversing it (and removing the root) seems to pass properly to Traefik, and the OpenSSL command. Thank you!